# Best way to convert strings to symbols in hash

Tags: ruby, hashmap

What's the (fastest/cleanest/straightforward) way to convert all keys in a hash from strings to symbols in Ruby?

This would be handy when parsing YAML.

```
my_hash = YAML.load_file('yml')
```

I'd like to be able to use:

```
my_hash[:key]
```

Rather than:

```
my_hash['key']
```

Comment: [dup](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8379596/119790)?

Comment: `hash.symbolize_keys` and `hash.deep_symbolize_keys` do the job if you're using Rails.

Comment: Josh if you would have put your comment into an answer, I would have voted you up. require 'rails';hash.deep_symbolize_keys works pretty well in irb or pry. :D

Answer (score 349, accepted):

In **Ruby >= 2.5** ([docs](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Hash.html#method-i-transform_keys)) you can use:

```
my_hash.transform_keys(&:to_sym)
```

Using older Ruby version? Here is a one-liner that will copy the hash into a new one with the keys symbolized:

```
my_hash = my_hash.inject({}){|memo,(k,v)| memo[k.to_sym] = v; memo}
```

With **Rails** you can use:

```
my_hash.symbolize_keys
my_hash.deep_symbolize_keys
```

Comment: That looks like it should work to me, but:
    
    my_hash = {'foo' => 'bar', 'fiz' => 'buzz'}
    my_hash.inject({}){|memo,(k,v)| memo[k.to_sym] = v; memo} 

    my_hash[:foo] # => nil
    my_hash['foo'] # => "bar" 

It's late and I'm tired. My brain might be missing some part of the puzzle, or the finer points of using inject().

Comment: Ah, sorry for being unclear - inject doesn't modify the caller. You need to do my_hash = my_hash.inject({}){|memo,(k,v)| memo[k.to_sym] = v; memo}

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for. I modified it a bit and added some lines to even create symbols in nestled hashes. Have a look here, if you're interested: http://www.any-where.de/blog/ruby-hash-convert-string-keys-to-symbols/

Comment: In Ruby 1.9 you can use `each_with_object` like so: `my_hash.each_with_object({}){|(k,v), h| h[k.to_sym] = v}`

Comment: this doesn't handle recursive hashes... Find for a one-off but not for DRY.

Comment: @BryanM. I've come into this discussion very late :-) but you can also use the `.tap` method to remove the need to pass `memo` at the end. I've created a cleaned up version of all solutions (recursive ones as well) https://gist.github.com/Integralist/9503099

Comment: Now with rails 4.1 and 4.2 is usefull to convert session hashes than are converted automatically

Comment: @baash05: here's a solution that hashes recursively:

```
  def recursively_memoize obj
    if obj.is_a?(Hash)
      memoized_obj ||= {}
      obj.each do |k, v|
        memoized_obj[k.to_sym] = recursively_memoize(v)
      end 

      return memoized_obj
    end

    obj
  end
```

Comment: i'm doing the other way, instead of symbolized key, i need quoted memo[k.to_s]
but what about if nested hash?

Comment: @SarahMei Your code examples seem ready to use but the 1st and 3rd need either a `my_hash = …` before or the `!` for the destructive variants to be really cut&paste ready. Could you add that?

Answer (score 319):

Here's a better method, if you're using Rails:

params.[symbolize_keys](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Hash.html#method-i-symbolize_keys)

The end.

If you're not, just rip off their code (it's also in the link):

```
myhash.keys.each do |key|
  myhash[(key.to_sym rescue key) || key] = myhash.delete(key)
end
```

Comment: The link is broken, but I can confirm that this works in rails 3.0.3

Comment: [to_options](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveSupport/CoreExtensions/Hash/Keys/to_options) is an alias for [sybolize_keys](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveSupport/CoreExtensions/Hash/Keys/symbolize_keys).

Comment: Will not symbolize nested hashes.

Comment: I switched the link to `symbolize_keys` with the new & working (Rails 3) URL. I originally just fixed the URL for `to_options`, but there's zero documentation at that link. `symbolize_keys` actually has a description, so I used that instead.

Comment: [deep_symbolize_keys!](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Hash.html#method-i-deep_symbolize_keys-21). Works on rails 2+

Comment: For those curious how to do the reverse, `hash.stringify_keys` works.

Comment: `my_hash = my_hash.deep_symbolize_keys` worked for me on Rails 3. Thanks @mastaBlasta!

Comment: [You can load the ActiveSupport core extensions in any Ruby project](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_support_core_extensions.html), not just rails: `require 'active_support/core_ext/hash'`

Comment: This also seem to be the fastest approach.

Answer (score 116):

For the specific case of YAML in Ruby, if the keys begin with '`:`', they will be automatically interned as symbols.

```
require 'yaml'
require 'pp'
yaml_str = "
connections:
  - host: host1.example.com
    port: 10000
  - host: host2.example.com
    port: 20000
"
yaml_sym = "
:connections:
  - :host: host1.example.com
    :port: 10000
  - :host: host2.example.com
    :port: 20000
"
pp yaml_str = YAML.load(yaml_str)
puts yaml_str.keys.first.class
pp yaml_sym = YAML.load(yaml_sym)
puts yaml_sym.keys.first.class
```

Output:

```
#  /opt/ruby-1.8.6-p287/bin/ruby ~/test.rb
{"connections"=>
  [{"port"=>10000, "host"=>"host1.example.com"},
   {"port"=>20000, "host"=>"host2.example.com"}]}
String
{:connections=>
  [{:port=>10000, :host=>"host1.example.com"},
   {:port=>20000, :host=>"host2.example.com"}]}
Symbol
```

Comment: Sweet! Is there a way to set `YAML#load_file` to default all keys to symbols instead of strings w/o having to begin every key with a colon?

Answer (score 68):

if you're using Rails, it is much simpler - you can use a HashWithIndifferentAccess and access the keys both as String and as Symbols:

```
my_hash.with_indifferent_access
```

see also:

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/HashWithIndifferentAccess.html

---

Or you can use the awesome "Facets of Ruby" Gem, which contains a lot of extensions to Ruby Core and Standard Library classes.

```
  require 'facets'
  > {'some' => 'thing', 'foo' => 'bar'}.symbolize_keys
    =>  {:some=>"thing", :foo=>"bar}
```

see also:
http://rubyworks.github.io/rubyfaux/?doc=http://rubyworks.github.io/facets/docs/facets-2.9.3/core.json#api-class-Hash

Comment: Actually that does the opposite. It converts from symbol to a string. To convert to a symbol use my_hash.symbolize_keys

Comment: #symbolize_keys only works in Rails - not in plain Ruby / irb. Also note that #symbolize_keys does not work on deeply nested hashes.

Answer (score 65):

Even more terse:

```
Hash[my_hash.map{|(k,v)| [k.to_sym,v]}]
```

Comment: This seems like the obvious choice.

Comment: It doesn't symbolize nested hashes.

Comment: A more readable version: `my_hash.map { |k, v| [k.to_sym, v] }.to_h`

Answer (score 59):

Since `Ruby 2.5.0` you can use [`Hash#transform_keys`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Hash.html#method-i-transform_keys) or [`Hash#transform_keys!`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Hash.html#method-i-transform_keys-21).

```
{'a' => 1, 'b' => 2}.transform_keys(&:to_sym) #=> {:a => 1, :b => 2}
```

Comment: Also works with transform_values https://apidock.com/rails/Hash/transform_values.

That's really nice because there doesn't seem to be an equivalent for modifying values like there is with `stringify_keys` or `symbolize_keys`.

Comment: is there a way to deep symbolize keys

Comment: This should be the chosen solution after 2018.

Answer (score 32):

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Hash.html#method-i-symbolize_keys

```
hash = { 'name' => 'Rob', 'age' => '28' }
hash.symbolize_keys
# => { name: "Rob", age: "28" }
```

Answer (score 31):

If you are using json, and want to use it as a hash, in core Ruby you can do it:

```rb
json_obj = JSON.parse(json_str, symbolize_names: true)
```

**symbolize_names**: If set to true, returns symbols for the names (keys) in a JSON object. Otherwise strings are returned. Strings are the default.

Doc: [Json#parse symbolize_names](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/json/rdoc/JSON.html#method-i-parse)

Comment: `symbol_hash = JSON.parse(JSON.generate(YAML.safe_load(FILENAME)), symbolize_names: true)` is a pretty DRY (but inefficient) way to quickly get a hash with nested keys as symbols if coming from a YAML file.

Answer (score 29):

Here's a way to deep symbolize an object

```
def symbolize(obj)
    return obj.inject({}){|memo,(k,v)| memo[k.to_sym] =  symbolize(v); memo} if obj.is_a? Hash
    return obj.inject([]){|memo,v    | memo           << symbolize(v); memo} if obj.is_a? Array
    return obj
end
```

Comment: nice one, I'll go with this one even if I would rename it deep_symbolize :)

Answer (score 21):

I really like the [Mash](http://www.intridea.com/2008/4/12/mash-mocking-hash-for-total-poser-objects?blog=company) gem.

you can do `mash['key']`, or `mash[:key]`, or `mash.key`

Comment: That's a very cool gem! Makes working with hashes very comfortable. Thanks for this!

Comment: So beautifully simple. New development on this project is being continued in Hashie (https://github.com/intridea/hashie) but it still works pretty much the same way: https://github.com/intridea/hashie#keyconversion

Answer (score 14):

A modification to @igorsales answer

```
class Object
  def deep_symbolize_keys
    return self.inject({}){|memo,(k,v)| memo[k.to_sym] = v.deep_symbolize_keys; memo} if self.is_a? Hash
    return self.inject([]){|memo,v    | memo           << v.deep_symbolize_keys; memo} if self.is_a? Array
    return self
  end
end
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you included why you were modifying the object for people scanning through answers.

Answer (score 13):

`params.symbolize_keys` will also work. This method turns hash keys into symbols and returns a new hash.

Comment: That method is not core Ruby. It is a Rails method.

Answer (score 13):

In Rails you can use:

```
{'g'=> 'a', 2 => {'v' => 'b', 'x' => { 'z' => 'c'}}}.deep_symbolize_keys!
```

Converts to:

```
{:g=>"a", 2=>{:v=>"b", :x=>{:z=>"c"}}}
```

Comment: `deep_symbolize_keys` is added in Rails' [Hash](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Hash.html#method-i-deep_symbolize_keys) extension, but it's not part of Ruby core.

Answer (score 8):

So many answers here, but the one method rails function is `hash.symbolize_keys`

Comment: You can only use it with rails: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Hash.html#method-i-symbolize_keys the default hash doesn't have it: http://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.0.0/Hash.html

Comment: rails only solution

Answer (score 8):

This is my one liner for nested hashes

```
def symbolize_keys(hash)
  hash.each_with_object({}) { |(k, v), h| h[k.to_sym] = v.is_a?(Hash) ? symbolize_keys(v) : v }
end
```

Comment: FYI, only works for Rails. In which case, HashWithIndifferentAccess may be a better alternative.

Comment: no it doesn't work only for rails. I works in plain ruby (irb) too. But it is only 2 levels deep. nested nested hashes don't get symbolized.

Answer (score 7):

In case the **reason** you need to do this is because your data originally came from JSON, you could skip any of this parsing by just passing in the `:symbolize_names` option upon ingesting JSON.

No Rails required and works with Ruby >1.9

```
JSON.parse(my_json, :symbolize_names => true)
```

Answer (score 5):

You could be lazy, and wrap it in a `lambda`:

```
my_hash = YAML.load_file('yml')
my_lamb = lambda { |key| my_hash[key.to_s] }

my_lamb[:a] == my_hash['a'] #=> true
```

But this would only work for reading from the hash - not writing.

To do that, you could use `Hash#merge`

```
my_hash = Hash.new { |h,k| h[k] = h[k.to_s] }.merge(YAML.load_file('yml'))
```

The init block will convert the keys one time on demand, though if you update the value for the string version of the key after accessing the symbol version, the symbol version won't be updated.

```
irb> x = { 'a' => 1, 'b' => 2 }
#=> {"a"=>1, "b"=>2}
irb> y = Hash.new { |h,k| h[k] = h[k.to_s] }.merge(x)
#=> {"a"=>1, "b"=>2}
irb> y[:a]  # the key :a doesn't exist for y, so the init block is called
#=> 1
irb> y
#=> {"a"=>1, :a=>1, "b"=>2}
irb> y[:a]  # the key :a now exists for y, so the init block is isn't called
#=> 1
irb> y['a'] = 3
#=> 3
irb> y
#=> {"a"=>3, :a=>1, "b"=>2}
```

You could also have the init block not update the hash, which would protect you from that kind of error, but you'd still be vulnerable to the opposite - updating the symbol version wouldn't update the string version:

```
irb> q = { 'c' => 4, 'd' => 5 }
#=> {"c"=>4, "d"=>5}
irb> r = Hash.new { |h,k| h[k.to_s] }.merge(q)
#=> {"c"=>4, "d"=>5}
irb> r[:c] # init block is called
#=> 4
irb> r
#=> {"c"=>4, "d"=>5}
irb> r[:c] # init block is called again, since this key still isn't in r
#=> 4
irb> r[:c] = 7
#=> 7
irb> r
#=> {:c=>7, "c"=>4, "d"=>5}
```

So the thing to be careful of with these is switching between the two key forms.  Stick with one.

Answer (score 4):

Would something like the following work?

```
new_hash = Hash.new
my_hash.each { |k, v| new_hash[k.to_sym] = v }
```

It'll copy the hash, but you won't care about that most of the time.  There's probably a way to do it without copying all the data.

Answer (score 4):

a shorter one-liner fwiw:

```
my_hash.inject({}){|h,(k,v)| h.merge({ k.to_sym => v}) }
```

Answer (score 3):

How about this:

```
my_hash = HashWithIndifferentAccess.new(YAML.load_file('yml'))

# my_hash['key'] => "val"
# my_hash[:key]  => "val"
```

Answer (score 3):

This is for people who uses `mruby` and do not have any `symbolize_keys` method defined:

```
class Hash
  def symbolize_keys!
    self.keys.each do |k|
      if self[k].is_a? Hash
        self[k].symbolize_keys!
      end
      if k.is_a? String
        raise RuntimeError, "Symbolizing key '#{k}' means overwrite some data (key :#{k} exists)" if self[k.to_sym]
        self[k.to_sym] = self[k]
        self.delete(k)
      end
    end
    return self
  end
end
```

The method:

- symbolizes only keys that are `String`
- if symbolize a string means to lose some informations (overwrite part of hash) raise a `RuntimeError`
- symbolize also recursively contained hashes
- return the symbolized hash
- **works in place!**

Comment: There's a typo in your method, you forgot the `!` in `symbolize_keys`. Otherwise works fine.

Answer (score 2):

## The array we want to change.

strings = ["HTML", "CSS", "JavaScript", "Python", "Ruby"]

## Make a new variable as an empty array so we can ".push" the symbols in.

symbols = [ ]

## Here's where we define a method with a block.

strings.each {|x| symbols.push(x.intern)}

## End of code.

So this is probably the most straightforward way to convert strings to symbols in your array(s) in Ruby. Make an array of strings then make a new variable and set the variable to an empty array. Then select each element in the first array you created with the ".each" method. Then use a block code to ".push" all of the elements in your new array and use ".intern or .to_sym" to convert all the elements to symbols.

Symbols are faster because they save more memory within your code and you can only use them once. Symbols are most commonly used for keys in hash which is great. I'm the not the best ruby programmer but this form of code helped me a lot.If anyone knows a better way please share and you can use this method for hash too!

Comment: The question was regarding hashes, not arrays.

Answer (score 2):

If you would like vanilla ruby solution and as me do not have access to `ActiveSupport` here is deep symbolize solution (very similar to previous ones)

```
    def deep_convert(element)
      return element.collect { |e| deep_convert(e) } if element.is_a?(Array)
      return element.inject({}) { |sh,(k,v)| sh[k.to_sym] = deep_convert(v); sh } if element.is_a?(Hash)
      element
    end
```

Answer (score 2):

Starting on **Psych** 3.0 you can add the [symbolize_names:](https://github.com/ruby/psych/commit/88ad4d50169306f4120ed41a1de9f081255c50fa) option

`Psych.load("---\n foo: bar")
 # => {"foo"=>"bar"}`

`Psych.load("---\n foo: bar", symbolize_names: true) 
 # => {:foo=>"bar"}`

Note: if you have a lower Psych version than 3.0 `symbolize_names:` will be silently ignored.

My Ubuntu 18.04 includes it out of the box with ruby 2.5.1p57

Answer (score 1):

```
ruby-1.9.2-p180 :001 > h = {'aaa' => 1, 'bbb' => 2}
 => {"aaa"=>1, "bbb"=>2} 
ruby-1.9.2-p180 :002 > Hash[h.map{|a| [a.first.to_sym, a.last]}]
 => {:aaa=>1, :bbb=>2}
```

Comment: You can wrap `a` in brackets to decompose the block argument to make this even more terse. See my answer for example.

Answer (score 1):

This is not exactly a one-liner, but it turns all string keys into symbols, also the nested ones:

```
def recursive_symbolize_keys(my_hash)
  case my_hash
  when Hash
    Hash[
      my_hash.map do |key, value|
        [ key.respond_to?(:to_sym) ? key.to_sym : key, recursive_symbolize_keys(value) ]
      end
    ]
  when Enumerable
    my_hash.map { |value| recursive_symbolize_keys(value) }
  else
    my_hash
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I like this one-liner, when I'm not using Rails, because then I don't have to make a second hash and hold two sets of data while I'm processing it:

```
my_hash = { "a" => 1, "b" => "string", "c" => true }

my_hash.keys.each { |key| my_hash[key.to_sym] = my_hash.delete(key) }

my_hash
=> {:a=>1, :b=>"string", :c=>true}
```

Hash#delete returns the value of the deleted key

Answer (score 1):

[Facets' Hash#deep_rekey](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/rubyworks/facets/Hash#deep_rekey-instance_method) is also a good option, especially:

- if you find use for other sugar from facets in your project,
- if you prefer code readability over cryptical one-liners.

Sample:

```
require 'facets/hash/deep_rekey'
my_hash = YAML.load_file('yml').deep_rekey
```

Answer (score 1):

In ruby I find this to be the most simple and easy to understand way to turn string keys in hashes to symbols :

```
my_hash.keys.each { |key| my_hash[key.to_sym] = my_hash.delete(key)}
```

For each key in the hash we call delete on it which removes it from the hash (also delete **returns the value associated with the key** that was deleted) and we immediately set this equal to the symbolized key.

Answer (score 1):

Similar to previous solutions but written a bit differently.

- This allows for a hash that is nested and/or has arrays.
- Get conversion of keys to a string as a bonus.
- Code does not mutate the hash been passed in.

  ```
  module HashUtils
    def symbolize_keys(hash)
      transformer_function = ->(key) { key.to_sym }
      transform_keys(hash, transformer_function)
    end

    def stringify_keys(hash)
      transformer_function = ->(key) { key.to_s }
      transform_keys(hash, transformer_function)
    end

    def transform_keys(obj, transformer_function)
      case obj
      when Array
        obj.map{|value| transform_keys(value, transformer_function)}
      when Hash
        obj.each_with_object({}) do |(key, value), hash|
          hash[transformer_function.call(key)] = transform_keys(value, transformer_function)
        end
      else
        obj
      end
    end
  end
  ```

Answer (score -1):

symbolize_keys recursively for any hash:

```
class Hash
  def symbolize_keys
    self.is_a?(Hash) ? Hash[ self.map { |k,v| [k.respond_to?(:to_sym) ? k.to_sym : k, v.is_a?(Hash) ? v.symbolize_keys : v] } ] : self
  end
end
```