# What does the Ruby method 'to_sym' do?

Tags: ruby, string, methods, symbols

What does the `to_sym` method do? What is it used for?

Answer (score 76, accepted):

`to_sym` converts a string to a symbol.  For example, `"a".to_sym` becomes `:a`.

It's not specific to Rails; vanilla Ruby has it as well.

It looks like in some versions of Ruby, a symbol could be converted to and from a Fixnum as well.  But `irb` from Ruby 1.9.2-p0, from ruby-lang.org, doesn't allow that unless you add your own `to_sym` method to Fixnum.  I'm not sure whether Rails does that, but it doesn't seem very useful in any case.

Comment: if you are using to_sym in your code, beware! You might have a leek. symbols are never unallocated by ruby.

Comment: @fotanus I assume you mean a memory **leak**, rather than some sort of vegetable: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leek

Comment: Hello @cHao, thank you for your answer. Could you please tell why `.to_sym!` (with `!`) doesn't work. I have used it in this ideone :  http://ideone.com/D7dZNz and it doesn't seem to be working. Thank you!

Comment: @GaurangTandon: Because strings don't have a `to_sym!` method.  The `!` at the end of a method name is actually part of the name. (Ruby lets method names end in `?` or `!`.)

Comment: @GaurangTandon: You may know this nine years later, but if string had a `to_sym!` method, that would imply we mean to change the original string into a symbol, which we probably don't, and that could possibly be problematic since the original string may be immutable. `to_sym` _returns_ a symbol from a string without attempting to change the original string.

Comment: @StevenHirlston wow, a nice decade long nostalgia haha  I stopped doing Ruby long ago so I didn't understand your comment fully, but I believe other visitors will. Thanks for the clarification!

Answer (score 1):

Expanding with useful details on the accepted answer by @cHao:
[`to_sym`](https://www.rubydoc.info/stdlib/core/String:to_sym) is used when the original `string` variable needs to be converted to a `symbol`.

In some cases, you can avoid `to_sym`, by creating the variable as `symbol`, not `string` in the first place. For example:

```
my_str1 = 'foo'
my_str2 = 'bar baz'

my_sym1 = my_str1.to_sym
my_sym2 = my_str2.to_sym

# Best:
my_sym1 = :foo
my_sym2 = :'bar baz'
```

or

```
array_of_strings = %w[foo bar baz]
array_of_symbols = array_of_strings.map(&:to_sym)

# Better:
array_of_symbols = %w[foo bar baz].map(&:to_sym)

# Best
array_of_symbols = %i[foo bar baz]
```

**SEE ALSO:**

[When to use symbols instead of strings in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16621073/967621)
[When not to use to_sym in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16289455/967621)
[Best way to convert strings to symbols in hash](https://stackoverflow.com/q/800122/967621)
[uppercase %I - Interpolated Array of symbols, separated by whitespace](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47992410/967621)