# Ruby: Converting a String with '.' to Symbol

Tags: ruby, mongoid

I have this string: `'industry.in'` and I want to convert it to `:industry.in`. When I do `'industry.in'.to_sym`, the result is: `:"industry.in"`.

Anyone know how to make it into: `:industry.in` instead?

I'm doing this so I could make a criteria query in Mongoid for an array field:

```
criteria = 'industry.in'.to_sym    
Company.where(criteria => ['Information Technology'])
```

Comment: Is there a method `in` on Symbol?

Comment: It's the same thing - you just can't write :foo.bar because ruby would think you wanted to call bar on that symbol. :"foo" is the same as :foo

Comment: Many query generators will use `=` for single item lists and `IN` for multiple lists. Is Mongoid like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's quite simple, actually. But first you have to understand what you're trying to do.

```
:industry.in
```

Here `:industry` is a Symbol, and `in` is a **method call** on that symbol. So, split the string into two parts, cast first part to symbol and use second part to call a method dynamically.

```
require 'mongoid'

s = 'industry.in'
parts = s.split('.') # => ["industry", "in"]
parts[0].to_sym.send(parts[1]) # => #<Origin::Key:0x007fa872ec0550 @name=:industry, @strategy=:__intersect__, @operator="$in", @expanded=nil, @block=nil>


# just the same as literal
:industry.in # => #<Origin::Key:0x007fa872ebf970 @name=:industry, @strategy=:__intersect__, @operator="$in", @expanded=nil, @block=nil>
```

Comment: This is exactly the answer I was looking for. Thanks! Will update the question with your answer.

Comment: Don't copy an answer into your question on Stack Overflow. Anyone viewing can easily see the answer you've selected.

Answer (score 5):

`:"industry.in"` is actually the `industry.in` symbol represented in a way that's copy/pastable.

If you type `:industry.in` directly you will get a "No method" error as Ruby will parse it as:

```
call #in method on :industry symbol
```

So, `'industry.in'.to_sym` is actually doing what you need.

Comment: My guess is that he's trying to build a query criteria. Something like `User.where(:age.in => [1, 2, 3])`.

Comment: and he can do that using `:"industry.in"` notation as it is exactly that - a notation. a way to represent an object so that parser doesn't freak out.

Comment: unless we're talking about some crazy monkey-patching of symbol objects in which case some library is not loaded..

Comment: "is actually doing what you need" - I'm not sure whether you (or I) know what he needs :)

Comment: agree. let's wait for author to clarify, i only explained the most straightforward scenario.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev, you were right that I'm building a query criteria using Mongoid
@keymone, using `:"industry.in"` doesn't work when doing the query. Had to manually assign :industry.in to a variable. Would be great though if there was some way to convert the `"industry.in"` string to Symbol. Any ideas?

Or is it even possible?

Comment: @Gjaldon: sure it's possible. See my answer :)

Answer (score -4):

**Rails method - to_sym**

These are same things.

`'industry.in'.to_sym` becomes `:industry.in`

Also, Please see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4062929/rails-method-to-sym) for more about to_sym.

Comment: I don't think so. It becomes `:"industry.in"`, which is completely different thing

Comment: You haven't read the SO link that I posted in the reply I suppose. Moreover, it is tested by me. Be sure to negate first.

Comment: I did test as well. Have *you* read that link? It doesn't cover this exact matter.

Comment: As posted there- "It's not specific to Rails, it looks like in some versions of Ruby, a symbol could be converted to and from a Fixnum as well." The matter is not exactly the same but it points to your first comment to be wrong in its sense. But again, it says its ruby specific. So I raise my hands.

Comment: Do you seriously not see the difference between `:industry.in` and `:"industry.in"`?

Comment: The difference is there but that's not the question to be asked. In my answer and in the link that I have posted, there is nothing like :"industry.in". I haven't commented about it too.

Comment: Well, read my first comment again. Your answer contains false information.

Comment: If my answer is false than the answer that got 13 upvotes is also false. See the heading of my post it is about `to_sym` to be more specific. If it is not exactly the answer, then also it is atleast helpful in regard of the question being asked.

Comment: @SaurabhJain, your answer is false. Converting the string `'industry.in'` to symbol returns `:"industry.in"` and not `:industry.in`. Try it out in IRB.