# equivalence of Ruby :symbol in Java?

Tags: java, ruby, symbols

[noticed the neat features of ruby symbols here](http://www.randomhacks.net/articles/2007/01/20/13-ways-of-looking-at-a-ruby-symbol)

Does java have anything similar to this? what would it be called?

D don't think a final string would do all the features. especially the way its stored and it would still need a toString for comparison.

Comment: Just to clarify: Ruby strings behaves like mutable but actually immutable like symbols. It internally creates new strings and replace the reference pointing to the new one

Comment: To specifically address storage and comparison, an `intern`ed `String` would provide analogous behavior (which string literals will normally be).

Answer (score -4, accepted):

A symbol in ruby is just an immutable string. The java equivalent would just be a normal `String`. I don't really see too many ruby specific features there, except maybe this memory leak one...

Answer (score 5):

Symbols are actually **immutable** identifiers. They can't change, <strike>are not garbage collected</strike>, and have performance advantages over Strings. I assume you already know what a String is. So the answer would be: Java doesn't have anything like Symbols.

Like @Idan said (and that is pretty clever) enums can be used as symbols <s>except they don't have methods that you can call on</s>. And symbols in Ruby are **not** immutable strings.

Refer to **[this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16621073/when-to-use-symbols-versus-strings-in-ruby)** if you want to know their core differences.

Comment: Saying enums don't have methods is misleading or misinformed.

Comment: @MattWhipple When I wrote this answer, I was indeed misinformed. Answer edited.

Answer (score 2):

The general answer to the "does Java have this feature?" question is "no!". However, [enums](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html) can usually solve the same problems symbols solve.

Comment: +1 to erase the downvote you we both got. Always thought downvotes without comments were pretty immature.

Comment: Awesome thanks wanted to rewrite some old java code to use it and i think enums will do the trick

Answer (score 1):

A Ruby symbol is an immutable string object which gets indexed in a symbol table for singe-reference re-use (hence the very inventive nomenclature!).

In Java, *all* `String` objects are immutable, and *all* of them are indexed in the (inventively named) symbol table for re-use by the JVM (as long as they are referenced and live).

So, in Java, a `String` (`"my_symbol"`) is the equivalent of a Ruby symbol (`:my_symbol`).

To get something equivalent to a Ruby `'my string'` (non-immutable), you'd have to go to more complex Java classes (`new StringBuilder("my string")`, etc.).  Or, if you have Groovy loaded the JVM, it overlays a similar mutable concept with [GString](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/index.html#all-strings).

Comment: The note about reuse is misleading. Literals are interned and reused but strings created at runtime are generally not (as evidenced by most heap dumps).

Comment: GStrings are also a different animal and aren't designed for the shared binding type behavior associated with mutable objects. I'd think if your design calls for aliasing like that it would be best expressed by a basic mutable bean with a string property and descriptive name...Or even an `AtomicReference<String>`

Comment: Or cut out the String wrapper and just use an Array or List of chars

Answer (score 0):

The closest thing you can get to a Ruby Symbol in Java would be calling `intern()` on a String.
While in Java you can have many String objects with the same content, `intern` ensures that it returns the same object for the same content (sequence of characters), thus it returns a canonical/distinct value.
So, while for generic Java Strings you have to call the `equals` method to check for content equality, for interned Strings you can simply use the `==` operator.

For further details, see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_interning