# Params, why are double quotes needed to extract the values?

Tags: ruby, authentication, sinatra

I am looking deeper into the login process with Sinatra.

**Login.erb**

```
<div id="flash" class="failure">
<h2>  <%= flash[:failure] %> </h2>
</div>


<a href="/welcome">Go Back</a>


<% if @user.nil? == false %>

<% if @user.errors.any? %>

<%= erb 'shared/_error_messages'.to_sym %>

<form action="/users/signin" method="post">
<p> User Login</p>

<label> Email <input type="text" name="[:session][:email]"/> </label></br>
<label> Password <input type="password" name="[:session][:password]"/> </label></br>

<input type="submit" value="Log in">

</form>
<% end %>

<% else %>

<form action="/users/signin" method="post">
<p> User Login</p>
<label> Email <input type="text" name="[:session][:email]"/> </label></br>
<label> Password <input type="password" name="[:session][:password]"/> </label></br>
<input type="submit" value="Log in">

</form>

<% end %>
```

When I use a binding.pry to determine what happens when we submit the post request I see that I will get the following:

```
[1] pry(#<Sinatra::Application>)> params
{
    ":session" => {
           ":email" => "tasha@gmail.com",
        ":password" => "123"
    }
}
```

I do know that I have a hash with the key-value pair.

I was wondering why do I need to put quotations around the symbols in the brackets instead of having it stand alone to pull the value out? Also, why if I named it without the double quotes why did it add the double quotes when I request the params in pry?

```
[2] pry(#<Sinatra::Application>)> params[:session]
nil
 [3] pry(#<Sinatra::Application>)> params[":session"]
 {
       ":email" => "tasha@gmail.com",
     ":password" => "123"
 }
[4] pry(#<Sinatra::Application>)> params[:session][:email]
 NoMethodError: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
from (pry):31:in `block in <main>'
[5] pry(#<Sinatra::Application>)> params[":session"][":email"]
"tasha@gmail.com"
[6] pry(#<Sinatra::Application>)>
```

Answer (score 2):

You field `name` for email is the *string* `[:session][:email]`, which gets parsed into the hash, with string type keys:

```
{
  ":session" => {
    ":email" => value
  }
}
```

These string keys start with a colon. *They are not symbols!*

And `params[:session]` will pull from `params["session"]`. This is because the string version of a symbol does not include the `:` prefix.

```
:session.to_s #=> "session"
```

You probably just want this in your template.

```
name="[session][email]"
```

Comment: Thank you!! I was wondering about that. For some reason, I see that people like to put the colons within the brackets but I guess it isn't needed.

Comment: You should read up on [the difference between strings and symbols.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16621073/when-to-use-symbols-versus-strings-in-ruby) It's important to understand in ruby.

Answer (score 1):

**Notice** the keys in your current params hash.

```
params
{
    ":session" => {
           ":email" => "tasha@gmail.com",
        ":password" => "123"
    }
}
```

You need to access keys in the params as they are defined. For example: `":session"`

The problem is that your hash is not generated correctly.

Comment: Thank you, should I change the way I name it?

Comment: Yes, the problem is with `:` prefix that you have added in the erb file. Please update the erb as suggested by @AlexWayne. That should fix incorrect key generation problem.