# Rails enum symbol vs string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, enums

I have just started working on a new rails project, and I have noticed that the previous developer has used strings instead of symbols as keys for the enum. The example is as follows:

```
enum event_type: {
  'Tournament'    => 1,
  'Practice Game' => 2
}
```

I am just curious about the possible advantages/disadvantages of  using strings instead of symbols.

Comment: As @AndreyDeineko pointed out in his answer it doesn’t matter in this case. Maybe you want to read [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16621073/when-to-use-symbols-instead-of-strings-in-ruby) for a better understanding of strings and symbols.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> The [mappings](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Enum.html) are exposed through a class method with the pluralized
> attribute name, which return the mapping in a
> `HashWithIndifferentAccess`

so whether you used strings or symbols both of the following will work:

```
MyModel.event_types[:Tournament]
MyModel.event_types['Tournament']
```

Comment: By default enums are integers in the database, but there is a lot of use cases for not going with the default. Especially when you want to keep your database readable / free of `magic number` code smell.  While this does not change the validity of the answer, the leading comment is misleading.
Here is a popular blog post on the subject:  https://blog.testdouble.com/posts/2019-06-03-enumerate-your-enums/

Comment: @SMAG you're right, my leading comment is not even directly related to the question, which is solely about string vs integer - edited, thx for pointing out