# Confusion between hashes and symbols

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash, symbols

May you help me understand the concept behind the hash and especially when we use symbols.

:name is a symbol right ?

we can use symbol as a key for our hashed right ?

`:name` and `name:` for example : those are two syntaxes but it describes a symbol right ?

when we have this for example :

```
Geocode.configure(

units: :km

)
```

here units does a reference to a specified argument called units in the configure function right ? and :km is the symbol we want to send through the variable unit or am I wrong ?

A last example :

```
validates :home_type, presence: true
```

Here we try to send to the validates function the symbol home_type right ?

and the second argument is named "presence" and we want to send the boolean true through this variable right ?

I am sorry if you don't understand my question, don't hesitate to ask me.

I got many headeck nderstanding those syntaxes.

Thanks a lot !

Comment: _"units does a reference to a specified argument called units"_ – you can't really tell whether this is a keyword argument or a hash. Ruby 2.x transparently converts between them, so `foo(a: 1)` and `foo({a: 1})` are effectively the same. Ruby 3.x is going to have "real" keyword arguments.

Comment: The answers down below explain the symbol syntactic sugar. For the difference between when to use a string as key and when to use a symbol as key I recommend checking out [*When to use symbols instead of strings in Ruby?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16621073/when-to-use-symbols-instead-of-strings-in-ruby).

Answer (score 1):

```
Geocode.configure(units: :km)
```

We are passing an hash to the `configure` method. This hash `{units: :km}`. Convenient syntax for `{:units => :km}`. So an hash with a key value pair with key symbol (`:units`) and value symbol (`:km`).

```
validates :home_type, presence: true
```

Here we are passing to the `validates` method a symbol `:home_type` and an hash, `{presence: true}`, or `{:presence => true`}. So the key is `:presence` symbol, the value is the boolean `true`.

Comment: Or maybe we are passing a keyword argument `units`, you'll never know ;-)

Comment: You're right! Either an hash or a keyword argument :)

Answer (score 1):

It is very basic & nothing but simplified convention in ruby

```
validates :home_type, presence: true, if: :check_user
```

is similar to

```
validates :home_type, { :presence => true, :if => :check_user }
```

So when I write as,

```
link_to 'Edit', edit_path(user), class: 'user_one', id: "user_#{user.id}"
```

In above, `link_to` is ActionHelper method which is taking 3 arguments where last one is hash `{ class: 'user_one', id: "user_#{user.id}" }`

Comment: _"nothing but simplified convention in rails"_ – this isn't Rails specific, Rails cannot alter Ruby's syntax.