# Using %i and %I symbol array literal

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Reading through a list of Rails questions, I'm having trouble finding what the %i does in relation to a symbol array.  Does this mean anything to anyone?

Comment: An example might help: `%i( one two three ) #=> [:one, :two, :three]`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> I'm having trouble finding what the `%i` does in relation to a symbol array.

It is an array literal for an array of symbols. It does the same thing in relation to symbol arrays as `'` does to strings.

Comment: Some useful examples here:
https://simpleror.wordpress.com/2009/03/15/q-q-w-w-x-r-s/

Comment: So %i and %I are almost the same thing as %w and %W.

Difference between "interpolated" and 'non-interpolated' is not obvious either, but it's the difference between double-quotes (which interpolate \n and #{...} items) and single-quotes (which do not)

Answer (score 58):

Lowercase `%i` stands for

> Non-interpolated Array of symbols, separated by whitespace (after Ruby 2.0)

In addition, uppercase `%I` means

> Interpolated Array of symbols, separated by whitespace (after Ruby 2.0)

**Example of difference regarding interpolation:**

```
2.4.2 :001 > a = 1
2.4.2 :002 > %i{one two #{a}+three} # Interpolation is ignored
 => [:one, :two, :"\#{a}+three"]
2.4.2 :003 > %I{one two #{a}+three} # Interpolation works
 => [:one, :two, :"1+three"]
```

Have a look at [here](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ruby_Programming/Syntax/Literals#The_%_Notation) for further information.