# How do I convert a Ruby hash so that all of its keys are strings

Tags: ruby, hash, stringify

I have a ruby hash which looks like:

```rb
{ id: 123, name: "test" }
```

I would like to convert it to:

```rb
{ "id" => 123, "name" => "test" }
```

Comment: The reverse of this: http://stackoverflow.com/q/8379596/1157054

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In pure Ruby (without Rails), you can do this with a combination of [`Enumerable#map`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html#method-i-map) and [`Array#to_h`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-to_h):

```
hash = { id: 123, name: "test" }
hash.map{|key, v| [key.to_s, v] }.to_h
```

Answer (score 5):

If you are using Rails or ActiveSupport:

```rb
hash = { id: 123, description: "desc" }
hash.stringify #=> { "id" => 123, "name" => "test" }
```

If you are not:

```rb
hash = { id: 123, name: "test" }
Hash[hash.map { |key, value| [key.to_s, value] }] #=> { "id" => 123, "name" => "test" }
```

Comment: Did you ask a question, only to answer it yourself immediately?

Comment: @AlexPan Yes I did. It's a feature of StackOverflow to provide an answer when submitting a question. The goal is knowledge sharing.

Comment: In newer Rails you use "hash.stringify_keys"
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Hash.html#method-i-stringify_keys

Answer (score 4):

I love `each_with_object` in this case :

```
hash = { id: 123, name: "test" }
hash.each_with_object({}) { |(key, value), h| h[key.to_s] = value }
#=> { "id" => 123, "name" => "test" }
```

Answer (score 4):

```
{ id: 123, name: "test" }.transform_keys(&:to_s)
  #=> {"id"=>123, "name"=>"test"}
```

See [Hash#transform_keys](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Hash.html#method-i-transform_keys).

Comment: I cheated. `transform_keys` was introduced in Ruby version 2.5, which did not appear until well after this question was posted.