# ruby to_yaml colon in keys

Tags: ruby, hash, yaml

I'm converting a hash to yaml in ruby but it adds : to keys:
For example:

```
:name: "Name"
:value: "Value"
```

If there a way to avoid and just output:

```
name: "Name"
value: "Value"
```

I can do this easily with gsub,
But just curious

Answer (score 6):

If you use string keys you won't get those prefixes. That's what happens when you serialize something with symbol keys.

In Rails or using ActiveSupport you can call [`deep_stringify_keys`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Hash.html#method-i-deep_stringify_keys) to convert them all prior to a `YAML.dump`.

Otherwise YAML is just trying to serialize and de-serialize as exactly as it can. A restored file with `:name: x` has `{ :name => 'x' }` as the resulting data.

Comment: There are pure Ruby ways to do this as well. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8379596/3784008) and [this answer in particular](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46978937/3784008).

Comment: with ruby 2.5 you can use `the_hash.transform_keys(&:to_s)`