# Hash key access via symbol not string

Tags: ruby

I have the following code. I don't understand why `table['something']` is different from `table[:something]`.

```
require 'json'
data = '[{"type":"local","db":"all","user":"postgres","addr":null,"method":"ident"},{"type":"local","db":"all","user":"all","addr":null,"method":"ident"},{"type":"host","db":"all","user":"all","addr":"0.0.0.0/0","method":"md5"},{"type":"host","db":"all","user":"all","addr":"::1/128","method":"md5"},{"type":"local","db":"communicator","user":"communicator","addr":" ","method":"trust"}]'
table = JSON.parse(data)
table.each do | auth |
  if (auth['user'])
    print( '\n\n\n' + auth[:user] )
  end
end
```

And on line with `print( '\n\n\n' + auth[:user] )`, I'm receiving an error:

```
TypeError: no implicit conversion of nil into String
        from (irb):88:in `+'
```

This means that accessing `table` via `:key` is different from `'key'`.
Why? How do I convert `table` to make it work with `:key` instead of `'key'`?

Comment: If You making `downvote` please write why

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `'key'` is a `String` and `:key` is a `Symbol` - those are two different things in Ruby.

It can be somewhat confusing, because `:'key'`, or `'key':` will also be a `Symbol` To make it work, just access `Hash` fields with a `Symbol`, like:

```
if (auth[:user])
```

To convert String indexed Hash to Symbol indexed Hash, refer to this question:

[Best way to convert strings to symbols in hash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/800122/best-way-to-convert-strings-to-symbols-in-hash)

Comment: How to convert my table to make it work with :key instead of 'key' ?

Comment: @WBAR, edited the answer.

Comment: I need to convert String based hast to Symbol based... Please read my question with understanding

Comment: @WBAR, this is a duplicate than.

Comment: can You show me the link ?

Comment: The best way is actually setting [`:symbolize_names`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.6/libdoc/json/rdoc/JSON.html#method-i-parse).

Comment: @cremno I was wondering why no one mentioned this as an answer and why everyone is trying to reinvent this. I was going to suggest it until I saw your comment.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `{"user":"postgres"}` in JSON means:

```
{"user" => "postgres"}
```

in Ruby whereas in Ruby it means:

```
{:user => "postgres"}
```

Since you have it as JSON, you need to access the value as:

```
auth["user"]
```

and not as:

```
auth[:user]
```

which is `nil` since the hash lacks the key `:user`.

Answer (score 1):

A Symbol :key is something other than a String 'key', just like a number 3 is something other than a String '3'. To convert a String to a key you can use key.to_sym

About the differance between the two other SO questions have been asked.
[What's the difference between a string and a symbol in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/255078/whats-the-difference-between-a-string-and-a-symbol-in-ruby)
See also [this](http://www.reactive.io/tips/2009/01/11/the-difference-between-ruby-symbols-and-strings/) article

EDIT
A solution to change your keys to symbol if you have no control over the source

```
require 'json'

data = '[{"type":"local","db":"all","user":"postgres","addr":null,"method":"ident"},{"type":"local","db":"all","user":"all","addr":null,"method":"ident"},{"type":"host","db":"all","user":"all","addr":"0.0.0.0/0","method":"md5"},{"type":"host","db":"all","user":"all","addr":"::1/128","method":"md5"},{"type":"local","db":"communicator","user":"communicator","addr":" ","method":"trust"}]'

table = JSON.parse(data)

p table
# [{"type"=>"local", "db"=>"all", "user"=>"postgres", "addr"=>nil, "method"=>"ident"}, {"type"=>"local", "db"=>"all", "user"=>"all", "addr"=>nil, "method"=>"ident"}, {"type"=>"host", "db"=>"all", "user"=>"all", "addr"=>"0.0.0.0/0", "method"=>"md5"}, {"type"=>"host", "db"=>"all", "user"=>"all", "addr"=>"::1/128", "method"=>"md5"}, {"type"=>"local", "db"=>"communicator", "user"=>"communicator", "addr"=>" ", "method"=>"trust"}]

table.map!{|auth| 
  new_auth = {}
  auth.each{|k, v| new_auth[k.to_sym] = v}
  new_auth
}

p table
# [{:type=>"local", :db=>"all", :user=>"postgres", :addr=>nil, :method=>"ident"}, {:type=>"local", :db=>"all", :user=>"all", :addr=>nil, :method=>"ident"}, {:type=>"host", :db=>"all", :user=>"all", :addr=>"0.0.0.0/0", :method=>"md5"}, {:type=>"host", :db=>"all", :user=>"all", :addr=>"::1/128", :method=>"md5"}, {:type=>"local", :db=>"communicator", :user=>"communicator", :addr=>" ", :method=>"trust"}]
```

Comment: How to convert my table to make it work with :key instead of 'key' ?

Comment: just change the print line in print( '\n\n\n' + auth['user'] )

Comment: I need to convert String based hast to Symbol based... Please read my question with understanding

Comment: change your source like {user: "postgres", ..} or convert the array afterward, I'll post an example

Comment: was called away, I posted the solution I proposed if you haven no control over the source