# Percent-format strings with named keys don't accept hashes with string keys?

Tags: ruby, string, formatting, printf

I am using the percent string formatting like so:

```
'fetching imap (%<host>s/%<user>s port=%<port>s...' % options
```

This works fine when the `options` hash has symbol keys `{ host: 'example.com' }`, but raises a `KeyError` when it has string keys `{ 'host' => 'example.com' }`:

```
KeyError: key<host> not found
```

This is problematic because Rails’ `HashWithIndifferentAccess` uses string keys by default. If using ActiveSupport, one solution is to call `symbolize_keys` on the hash.

Is there an alternative way to make the `String#%` method try string keys as well as symbol keys?

Is this a bug in Ruby that deserves a bug report? Or are there reasons for enforcing this behavior, like the edge case where both `:host` and `'host'` keys exist?

Comment: Why would this be a bug? I don't understand your thoughts. At most, it could be a feature request (although I would be strongly against it).

Answer (score 2):

It's not a bug that Ruby doesn't treat strings and symbols interchangeably; as you note, you're using *Rails'* HashWithIndifferentAccess, which exists exactly because Ruby regularly considers strings and symbols unrelated.

This is a similar situation to keyword arguments, which also do not allow string-keyed hashes.

At best, you could try to argue that `sprintf` should use the ruby-level accessors methods (`[]` or `fetch`), which HashWithIndifferentAccess overrides, instead of directly doing the C-level `rb_hash_lookup2`.

Alternatively, Rails might be able to make this work by partly restoring the `default` behaviour that existed between [`c918a3a0691`](https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/c918a3a0691) and [`a218a35e660`](https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/a218a35e660).

Answer (score 0):

> I am using the percent string formatting … This works fine when the options hash has symbol keys … but raises a KeyError when it has string keys
>
> If using ActiveSupport [from Rails], one solution is to call `symbolize_keys` on the hash.

For **a solution without Rails** you can use:

```
options = options.transform_keys(&:to_sym)
```

or

```
options.transform_keys!(&:to_sym)
```

See [the manual.](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Hash.html#method-i-transform_keys) This requires Ruby 2.5.0 or higher, though. For more options, also for earlier Ruby versions, see [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/800122).